# Writing to `*mut u8` from immutable context

Tags: windows, rust, windows-rs

I have a struct containing a raw pointer to data I'm getting from somewhere else (in this case, a memory-mapped file opened through <del>[`OpenFileMappingA`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-openfilemappinga)</del> [`CreateFileMappingA`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-createfilemappinga) which I'll need to write for IPC purposes, after mapping it through [`MapViewOfFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-mapviewoffile). Linking the C++ docs because the Rust ones only provide the signature. For brevity I'll skip the calls to `MapViewOfFile` and checking error statuses; the actual code is handling this. But the compiler is currently allowing me to use a `*const u8` or `*mut u8` struct field in a non-mutably borrowed reference for *writing* to. As a sanity check, I'd love to know:

- is this still sound code?
- is this safe to do when the source of my data provides me a `*mut c_void`?
- are there any safety and soundness pitfalls other than `null` pointers and uninitialized data?

This is *not* a question about mutating some immutable ref I don't own. Somehow all "similar" questions SO provide are about coercing immutable to mutable, which isn't the case here.

```rs
use windows::Win32::System::Memory::MEMORY_MAPPED_VIEW_ADDRESS as MmfAddr;
// omit other uses

pub struct MemMappedFile {
    mmf_ptr: MmfAddr, // field Value is a *mut c_void
    other_ptr: *const u8, // the first N bytes of the above pointer are used for metadata
    opened: bool,
    // Other fields for safety and sanity handling
}

impl MemMappedFile {
    pub fn write_bytes(&self, bytes: &[u8]) -> Result<(), windows_core::Error> {
        // omit sanity checks -- real code errors if bytes.len() > 
        let count = bytes.len();
        let byte_ptr = bytes.as_ptr();
        unsafe { std::ptr::copy(byte_ptr, self.mmf_ptr.Value.cast(), count)};
        windows::Win32::Foundation::GetLastError()?
    }

    pub fn write2(&self, bytes: &[u8]) {
        // omit checks here too
        let count = bytes.len();
        let byte_ptr = bytes.as_ptr();
        unsafe { std::ptr::copy(byte_ptr, self.other_ptr.cast_mut(), count)};
    }

    pub fn magical_constructor(/* args go here */) -> Result<Self, windows_core::Error> {
        // Omit opening and mapping the file and whatnot, this creates the pointers
        // and all pointers are guaranteed to be valid.
        // I also make sure to zero out all bytes in the mmf before instantiating Self
    }
}
```

I'd, quite frankly, expect the compiler to throw a fit on either the writes (`&self` is not `mut`) or on the `cast_mut()` on the `*const u8` for the same reasons.

This compiles and *seems* to work (in non-IPC reads and writes anyway) but looks fishy; I know I'm using an explicitly mutable pointer in one case, but Rust is usually very strict and I've never had to use as much `unsafe` code as the `windows-rs` crate is asking me to use (there doesn't seem to be COM or WinRT interfaces for this and I need a fast way to share a few MB between applications on the same host)

---

Additional info thanks to an insightful comment:
Named Shared memory is created using the invalid filehandle and namespaces, [see the relevant docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/memory/creating-named-shared-memory) for more info. All of these functions are exposed through the `windows-rs` crate (mostly marked as `unsafe`) and plenty of them return `Result`s. Not to mention one could call `GetLastError()` which is set from the OS side of things and is translated into a Rust implementation of the errors. (beware with that function though; the error enum contains `OK` which tripped me up)

Comment: The borrow checker is concerned with *references* only. Once you have a pointer, anything goes. `&foo as *const Foo as *mut Foo` is perfectly valid code. That said, you cannot reliably use memory-mapped files on Windows from Rust. Rust doesn't provide any way to handle SEH exceptions.

Comment: This code is being run as a system service with all the right permissions for what it does; any exceptions that _might_ occur such as I/O errors on writes should be a non-issue considering this is specifically about memory _not_ backed by an on-disk file. Well, backed by the pagefile, but the OS handles that one entirely out of developer control. Should I add that into the question?

Comment: A key insight for me on that topic was that pointers are `Copy` so even if it is behind a shared reference to begin with, you can always copy it out and have a bare pointer, which obviously you can write to.

Comment: @iinspectable [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/windows-rs/issues/2681#issuecomment-1766695094) (and the rest of the thread) seem to imply that calling `MapViewOfFile` should provide a (from the program's perspective) continuous memory region to write to. I'm using that call in my existing code already - but do notice I forgot to mention that in the initial question. If you'd turn your comment for the "anything goes with a raw pointer" into an answer, I'll gladly mark it accepted

Comment: On second thought, why isn't `other_ptr` a `*mut u8` to begin with? That would more closely resemble facts, and it's still a `*mut u8` even when `MemMappedFile` is bound to `&self` (as opposed to `&mut self`).

Comment: If you mash those comments into a coherent answer, I'll gladly mark it accepted. This has definitely been very helpful for me in understanding working with raw pointers.
SEH exceptions aside, `windows-rs` passes more my way than I'd expect considering how much they're raving about Rust